# How to launch browser using selenium with cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I am newbie for cucumber framework, I have worked on selenium webdriver using testNG framework. I have to start cucumber framework, I have installed cucumber plugin to eclipse but dont know how to start writting code.

And what is the difference between cucumber and cucumber-jvm, and which is the best?

Could anyone pls help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can find lots of info on what dependecies you should use for your project on the Cucumber main site [Cucumber Documentation](https://cukes.info/docs#installation)

Cucumber base is Ruby

Cucumber-JVM is Java

- start with creating a src/test/resources
- create a file named anything you want (keep it to the thing you want to test) and end it with .feature

```
Feature: Calculator should work accourding to standard calculator devices

  Scenario: addition
    Given a calculator I just turned on
    When I add 4 and 5
    Then the result is 9
```

- put this in as a guide line and try to run it. it should give you a call missing steps.
- create a new java file in src/test/java and call it RunCukesTest this wil later be the starter of all your features.
- the output you just got from the feature in the console can be put in a .java call it something to do with the feature like CalculatorSteps.java put this in the same folder as your RunCukesTest.java

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = false,
        plugin = {"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"} ,
        features = "src/test/resources/cucumber",
        tags = "~@ignore"
        )
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

this is the basic you need to start using Cucumber (there is a start example on  [github](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton))

Now the Selenium question

- you will have to initiate a WebDriver _driver;
- with driver you create a new ChromeDriver or FireFoxDriver etc
- some browsers need a installation [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) firefox is built in (to my best knowledge)
- see the code below
- ask if there is anything you don't get

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import cucumber.api.java.en.*;

import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Timeout;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class NavigationSteps {

    WebDriver _driver;

    @Given("^i am at \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_am_at_home(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        _driver = new ChromeDriver();

        _driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        _driver.get(arg1);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    @When("^i click on \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_click_on(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        _driver.findElement(By.linkText(arg1)).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    @Then("^i expect the title to be \"(.*?)\"\"(.*?)\"$")
    public void i_expect_the_title_to_be(String arg1, String arg2)  throws Throwable {
        String result = (arg1 + " | " + arg2); 

        Thread.sleep(200);
        assertEquals("Title should be",result,_driver.getTitle());
        tearDown();

    }

    @Then("^Header should contain \"(.*?)\"$")
    public void header_should_contain(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        Thread.sleep(200);
        assertEquals("Title should be", arg1, _driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div[1]/div/h1")).getText());
        tearDown();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException
    {

        _driver.quit();
    }

}
```

EDIT - answers to the questions in nicer format

1. feature file calls the java file (Run via RunCukesTest or feature file)

   - the methods to test go into je java steps file
   - Feature calculator has a CalculatorSteps.java file the scenario is in the feature file the methods in the steps
2. No, the console outputs this as a Regex to identify the corresponding step the test u write in the method below it.

```
Given a calculator I just turned on
        results into
        @Given ("^a calculator I just turned on$")
        public void iCanCallThisAnythingIWant(){
        #do something
        }
```

3. see answer 2
4. Given When Then are the logical way to read a Scenario to keep things readable it should be used in that way. If you find yourself with a long Given When or Then u can split the sentence with a "and" in between. but it doesn't matter in what way u write them.

Comment: Hello Stevens, Thank you so much for you detailed explaination. Ya now I got some idea about cucumber. But still I have some doubts, it may be very silly but It is very usefull to me. Could you please clarify below doubts?
1. Here which one is executable file (feature file or java file), in which file we need to write test steps like calling the methods e.g. launch the browser, navigate to pages etc..
2. The sentence after the Given, when and then serves as method names rite? in which we have to rite the actual java code.

Comment: 3. The code you have written in the class NavigationSteps, you have written Given, when, then for the methods only, I dint get that.

Kindly reply.

Comment: Hi Stevens, I just wrote code to start firefox and launch URL, Now I got to know that feature file is executable file.
I have one doubt i.e. We can annotate the method with Given, When etc.. should we use these methods according to the annotation? Or we can use radomly?
kindly reply.

Comment: 1. You run the feature file that in turn searches for the given, when & then. You write your scenario in the .feature file and use the output of that in the .....steps.java file

2. no, the sentence after those 3 is the identifier for cucumber, example Given Test1 will search for a regex exactly called Test1 and exec the method underneath. you can have a very long Given and call it public void do_something aslong as the @given is the same as in the feature

3. see 2 it is the identifier for cucumber Given should exec this method When that method and Then that method.

Comment: it doesnt matter in what way u put them, Given When Then is just a logical way of writing a scenario. u have a Given that u have access to something When u change something Then u want this as outcome. but if you write it as Then Given Given When.... etc it will just run it in that order

Comment: Thanks Stevens, Can we call more than one method in a single Given through feature file? and Is there any common annotation that can be used for methods e.g. Now I have used Given, When, and Then? It is little confusing to me. I am using eclipse IDE, I am unable to navigate to the method from feature file.

Comment: Currently using IntelliJ for my projects and there you can quickly switch between places with Ctrl + clicking on the method or in the feature file but a quick scan of Eclipse and it doesn't seem to work there. You can call a other method within the method but not from the feature file to my knowledge

Comment: Thanks Stevens, I have installed inteij and created class and feature file as I did in eclipse, but when I run the feature file it is displaying as Undefined step: Given  launch the browser, the same code is working fine in eclipse. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: if there is a Undefined step it should post the method in your console. Copy that into your steps class.

Comment: No I have written the step definition, still it is saying undefined.... I am using Inteij, is there anything I need to setup in Intelij to run cucumber test?

Comment: I guess I need to install cucumber-java plugin to intelij.